# implementation of dot function `.()` in data.table package

Tags: r, function, data.table

from `?data.table::data.table` :

> The expression '.()' is a shorthand alias to list(); they both mean
>   the same

However this function is nowhere to be found :

```
data.table:::.
```

> Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) :
>   object '.' not found

So I suppose the input is parsed somehow, how is it done ? I'd like to use the same feature in my own package.

The following works not too bad :

```
test  <- function(x) {
  eval(substitute(
    eval.parent(substitute(x, list(.=list)))
    ))
}

foo <- "bar"
test(.(foo))
# [[1]]
# [1] "bar"
identical(test(.(foo)), list(foo))
# [1] TRUE
```

However there will be some dot variables used inside this dot function, and this fails :

```
. <- "baz"
test(.(foo,.))
# [[1]]
# [1] "bar"
# 
# [[2]]
# function (...)  .Primitive("list")
```

Expected :

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "bar"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "baz"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `data.table` package accomplishes it with this bit of code

```
replace_dot_alias <- function(e) {
  # we don't just simply alias .=list because i) list is a primitive (faster to iterate) and ii) we test for use
  # of "list" in several places so it saves having to remember to write "." || "list" in those places
  if (is.call(e)) {
    # . alias also used within bquote, #1912
    if (e[[1L]] == 'bquote') return(e)
    if (e[[1L]] == ".") e[[1L]] = quote(list)
    for (i in seq_along(e)[-1L]) if (!is.null(e[[i]])) e[[i]] = replace_dot_alias(e[[i]])
  }
  e
}
```

found in [`R/data.table.R`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R) (currently at line 173). That's why you don't find `data.table:::.` anywhere, and how they accomplish the parsing you mention in your post.

Then in `[.data.table" <- function (x, i, j,`... they can do this sort of thing

```
if (!missing(j)) {
    jsub = replace_dot_alias(substitute(j))
    root = if (is.call(jsub)) as.character(jsub[[1L]])[1L] else ""
```

....

Comment: Brilliant! And this function will yield me my expected output : `test  <- function(x) eval.parent(data.table:::replace_dot_alias(substitute(x)))`

Comment: Precisely! Is this for the same `composer` package as a question from a couple days ago?

Comment: It is indeed, I'm having fun with this, it just striked me that `[[` was redundant for vectors and there's a lot of fun things it could be used for.

Comment: I suppose that a similar same sleight of hand is used by `dplyr::n` , which exists but only contains `abort("This function should not be called directly")`

Comment: I'm sure that's right